# Dirac delta - sifting

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

We know
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-a)f(x) \, dx=f(a)  $

Is this still true for:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(a-x)f(x) \, dx=f(a)  $

In general, can we call dirac delta even function?

Comment: Look at representations of the delta function, they are all even...

Answer (score 2):

"Formally", you can substitute $u=a-x$ to get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(a-x) f(x) \, dx = \int_\infty^{-\infty} -\delta(u) f(a-u) \, du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(u) f(a-u) \, du.$$

Then the last quantity is $f(a-u)$ evaluated at $u=0$, i.e. $f(a)$.

Comment: Is that really formal, though?  The integral notation is meaningless in the sense that it doesn't really refer to an integral, right?

Comment: @user46944 "Formally" in this sense means "only formally", that is, I haven't given the justification for why I can do this manipulation, but this is the manipulation that I "should" be able to do. To really justify this, one should be more careful, for instance by passing to an approximating sequence.

Comment: Yeah, it's the manipulation we should be able to do if we are dealing with an actual integral. But I've been told the integral notation is just short hand because the dirac delta functional is a linear functional.  From this point of view I feel like you are manipulating a notation to justify a property of the dirac delta functional.

Comment: @user46944 That's right. But on the other hand, how are you defining the composition of a distribution with a function in the first place? The obvious way is by passing to an approximating sequence of the distribution. If you do that it pretty much falls out by ordinary manipulations.

Comment: So by "passing to an approximating sequence of a distribution", do you mean finding a sequence of actual functions $\delta_{n}$ such that the distribution they define is *actually* integration and the limit of the distributions converges to the dirac delta distribution?

Comment: @user46944 Yes. For the Dirac delta this is an especially standard technique; in this case the approximating sequence is called an *approximate identity*. (The name is because the Dirac delta is the identity element for the convolution operator.)

Comment: @user46944 : "Formally" means it's not logically justified but you do it anyway.

Comment: So here, when you say "formally", you are saying "if we were in a classical context where integration makes sense, this is what should happen, but we are not in a classical context, but since we want to be consistent with the classical context, then we are saying this *has* to work out this way".

Comment: It remains to be shown that the equalities *actually* hold though, in the context where we are not talking about integration.  So your answer is really saying "if you believe that the manipulations of distributions should be consistent with integration, then we have this".  But you haven't proved that distributions are consistent with integration, which I think would be something that must be shown.

Comment: @user46944 Here's the thing: we don't have a prior definition of the distribution associated to the "function" "$x \mapsto \delta(a-x)$". This manipulation furnishes that definition. The definition is consistent with integration in the sense that $f_n(x) \to \delta(x)$ in distribution then $f_n(a-x) \to \delta(a-x)$ in distribution as well. Indeed the manipulation that I used to come up with the definition is essentially the proof of this consistency. (The only remaining step is an interchange of limit and "integral", which is free because we've assumed convergence in distribution).

Comment: @Ian And If I understand correctly, this is because $\delta(x)$ can be defined as the limit of $f_{n}(x)$, so that by the **definition** it follows that $\delta ( a - x)$ is the limit of $f_{n}(a - x)$.  Is that right?  It's a matter of definition, not something we have to *check* or *prove*.

Comment: @user46944 We should try to make the boundary between definition and proof explicit here. We *define* $\delta(a-x)$ to be the distribution $f \mapsto f(a)$. Because of the manipulation above (which would be completely rigorous if $\delta$ were a continuous function), it follows that if $f_n(x) \to \delta(x)$ then $f_n(a-x) \to \delta(a-x)$. This part has been *proven*.

Comment: @Ian Let me rephrase the middle of your last sentence.  "Which would be completely rigorous if $\delta$ were a continuous function (it's not even a function)".  Since it's not rigorous, don't we have to have some other rigorous means of checking the property?

Comment: @user46944 I spoke sloppily. The calculation in my answer would be completely rigorous if you replaced $\delta$ with a continuous function $g$. Consequently if we define $\delta(a-x)$ to be the distribution $f \mapsto f(a)$, and we have continuous functions $g_n$ converging to $\delta$ in the distributional topology, then $g_n(a-x)$ converges to $\delta(a-x)$ in the distributional topology as well. To prove this, just write the first equality with $g_n$ instead of $\delta$, take limits on both sides, and interchange limit and "integral" (which is "free" in the distributional topology).

Comment: @Ian My brain hurts.  I'm going to take a break and come back and reread all of your comments until I understand them.  I don't think I'll comment again because I think you've already written everything that needs to be said, and I just have to put in the effort to understand it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user46944 Let me try to compile the above for when you return, so you don't have to trudge through so much stuff. First suppose $g_n$ are continuous functions converging to $\delta$ in the distributional topology. Now $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(a-x) f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(x) f(a-x) dx$ by integration by substitution.

Comment: @user46944 If we now take limits in $n$ on both sides, on the right side, by the definition of convergence in the distributional topology, we get $\langle \delta,f(a-x) \rangle = f(a)$ by the definition of $\delta$. Therefore the limit of the left side is also $f(a)$. Now we look at the expression $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(a-x) f(x) dx$. We interpret this as $\left \langle \left ( \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(a-x) \right ),f \right \rangle$, where the inner limit is in the distributional topology. Now we just give the "suggestive name" $\delta(a-x)$ to the inner limit.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for compiling that information.  There is only one thing confusing about what you've written.  How did you justify interchanging the limit and the integral in the last idea?  I know you said something about the distributional topology.

Comment: @user46944 The main important fact about the distributional topology is that $\phi_n \to \phi$ in distribution iff $\phi_n(f) \to \phi(f)$ for all test functions $f$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle \phi_n,f \rangle = \langle \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_n,f \rangle$ is automatic, in the sense that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi_n$ is defined so that this equality holds. So in my notation above you could've written $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle g_n(a-x),f(x) \rangle = \langle \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(a-x),f(x) \rangle$, then we call the inner limit $\delta(a-x)$.

Comment: @Ian So it's again a definition thing rather than something you prove/verify.  By definition, $\langle \delta, \phi \rangle := \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \langle g_{n}, \phi \rangle$ for every test function $\phi$.

Comment: @user46944 That depends a little bit on what you mean by "it", but I think I agree.

Comment: @user46944 Actually no, there is still a thing to check as I pointed out before, which is the independence of the choice of approximating sequence. The philosophy for that is that for a distribution $f$, and an operator $A$ mapping distributions to distributions, aim to define $Af$ as $\phi \mapsto \langle f,B\phi \rangle$ where $B$ is some operator which maps test functions to test functions.

Comment: @Ian I mean $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_{n}$ doesn't exist as a function, so its inner product with $\phi$ doesn't make sense.  But $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \langle g_{n}, \phi \rangle$ makes sense (if the limit exists, anyway), and so we can define $\langle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_{n}, \phi \rangle :=  \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \langle g_{n}, \phi \rangle$.  No need to justify passing the limit since it's a definition.  Of course we would then need to know the limit on the right hand side exists.

Comment: @user46944 Your point here is just notation: I write $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ to mean the bilinear form between distributions and test functions. This notation is reasonable because for distributions given by integration against $L^2$ functions, this bilinear form is just the $L^2$ inner product. But at the end of the day it is just a notation. It is also fairly standard and much less prone to being misleading than the integral notation.

Comment: @Ian I understand your point, but my point also still holds.  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_{n}$ may not exist, so we can't talk about $\langle \lim \limits_{n \to\infty} g_{n}, \phi \rangle$ unless we define it as above.

Comment: @user46944 Yes and no. Because of our definition of convergence, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ exists, it must satisfy $\langle \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n,\phi \rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle g_n,\phi \rangle$ for all test functions $\phi$. But this latter limit can actually be computed: it will be $\phi(0)$. Since this defines a distribution, we can define $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ to be this distribution. (Maybe I'm going in confusing circles and you already understand this point.)

Comment: @Ian So this would be a perfect place to use the word "formally".  "Formally", it must satisfy $\langle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_{n}, \phi \rangle = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \langle g_{n}, \phi \rangle$.  Right?  It's because we *want* this to be satisfied, not because of some other reason that it "must" be satisfied.

Comment: @user46944 The equality has to hold for $g_n$ to be converging in distribution to anything. The original calculation is "formal" in the sense that it doesn't pass to an approximating sequence at all.

Comment: @Ian But that's by definition of converging in distribution.  I feel like we are going around in circles.  Why *must* $\langle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_{n}, \phi \rangle = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \langle g_{n}, \phi \rangle$?  Well, by definition of convergence in distribution.  I think.  I don't know why the equality **must** be true.

Comment: @user46944 *If* $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ exists *then* $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle g_n,\phi \rangle = \langle \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n,\phi \rangle$. Thus we can compute what the limit *must* be by assuming it exists and then calculating it. If we wanted to be pedantic about it, we would then go back and prove that the sequence converges to the limit that we anticipate without first assuming that the limit exists. But yes, we are going in circles a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because $\delta(x-a)$ "activates" when the argument is equal to zero, so it's irrelevant if you write $\delta(x-a)$ or $\delta(a-x)$ because $a-x=0$ is the same statement as $x-a=0$.

A more formal way to show that is to use the formula for when the argument of $\delta$ is a function: $$\delta(f(x))=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\left|f'(x_i)\right|},$$ where $x_i$ are the points satisfying $f(x_i)=0$. In this case $f(x)=a-x$ and $|f'(a)|=1$, so $\delta(a-x)=\delta(x-a)$, and so the distribution is, in a way, even.

Substitution also works, as the other answers suggest.

Comment: I am so confused by this answer.  What does it mean for $\delta(x-a)$ to "peak" at an argument when it's not even a defined function?

Comment: That's a heuristic argument, I'm editing the answer right now to include a formal one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to reading it.  My understanding of the dirac delta function is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the change of variable, let $u=a-x$,

Also note that: 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx=\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}-du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty du$